# What would be the best way to find foreign professors for a PhD defense panel?

Tags: phd, thesis, thesis-committee, india

I need some researchers to review my PhD thesis. I am from India and my university is also in India; the research data was collected in India. My university rules say my thesis should be reviewed by experts from the same field and another country before submitting it.

**Question:** What would be the best way to find specialists in a specific field to participate in a PhD evaluation panel or as reviewers? Should I just leave it to my supervisor?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a suitable question for this site. You should really discuss this with your supervisor.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. I have edited your question in order to comply with the rules of our community. I hope that the answer for this question may also help you.

Comment: I voted to reopen your question as I think it is answerable now. Still, it may help if you [edit] your question to include further details regarding your university’s regulations: 1) Why would you need experts to review your thesis *before* you submit it? Shouldn’t your thesis be submitted/transmitted to the reviewers so they can review it? 2) Why is the origin of your data relevant? 3) How can a thesis be an “international paper”?

Comment: _My university rules say my thesis should be reviewed by experts_ What are the criteria your university use to determine the people you find are experts?

Comment: In this case, you can find the researchers/professors from the references that you used most in your thesis. This is the best way to find the experts in your area to evaluate your thesis. Then, you may give the list of experts to your supervisor for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've written a thesis on the topic, **you** should know who the experts are.  They are the authors of the papers you read and cited.  Hopefully you have also met them at conferences.  Of course, your advisor should also know these people.